# Illustrator stopped snapping to guidelines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, snapping, guides

I don't know what I did, but Adobe Illustrator stopped to snap to guides.

I draw just rectangle and can't snap it.

Maybe it is related that I was experimenting with distributing guides between layers and groups, but now they are all in the same layer, than an object.

Also I have multiple artboards, but I don't see any sign that guide belong to artboard.

Answer (score 7):

Check your Smart Guides are on. Usually when things aren't snapping the way I think they should be, it's usually because I've hit a keyboard shortcut and turned them off by mistake**.

[image]

** usually while working with type and trying to underline something... The keyboard shortcut for Smart Guides is CMD+U.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure both these features are checked in your AI

- `View > Snap To Point`
- `View > Smart Guides`

For detailed info read the [official docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html).

Comment: Also when all esle fails holding control down while dragging enables more snaps. Offcourse smart guides have to be on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the real answer for those of you with illustrator cc 2019. I found this out by playing around. TURN OFF show bounding box. Also make sure you have smart guides TURNED ON and "Alignment Guides" Checked in preferences. This works for both text and objects! Once you do that it all snaps no problem!! So glad adobe tech could not figure that one out....geezz

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that if the guides are on a locked level, the objects do not snap. The level must be unlocked.

Comment: Hi Marcello, welcome to GD.SE. We usually like longer answers with more details or pictures. Can you expand on your current answer?

Comment: yes that's work great and just to be sure hold ctrl with the unlocked guidelines
Thanks